# Scraping with BeautifulSoup: object has no attribute

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to extract excerpts of data like company name and address from a website using BeautifulSoup. I am getting, however, the following failure:

```
Calgary's Notary Public 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    print item.find_all(class_='jsMapBubbleAddress').text
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'text'
```

The HTML code snippet is here. I want to extract all the text information and convert into a CSV file. Please any one help me.

```
<div class="listing__right article hasIcon">
   <h3 class="listing__name jsMapBubbleName" itemprop="name"><a data-analytics='{"lk_listing_id":"100971374","lk_non-ad-rollup":"0","lk_page_num":"1","lk_pos":"in_listing","lk_proximity":"14.5","lk_directory_heading":[{"085100":[{"00910600":"1"},{"00911000":"1"}]}],"lk_geo_tier":"in","lk_area":"left_1","lk_relevancy":"1","lk_name":"busname","lk_pos_num":"1","lk_se_id":"e292d1d2-f130-463d-8f0c-7dd66800dead_Tm90YXJ5_Q2FsZ2FyeSwgQUI_56","lk_ev":"link","lk_product":"l2"}' href="/bus/Alberta/Calgary/Calgary-s-Notary-Public/100971374.html?what=Notary&amp;where=Calgary%2C+AB&amp;useContext=true" title="See detailed information for Calgary's Notary Public">Calgary's Notary Public</a> </h3>
   <div class="listing__address address mainLocal">
      <em class="itemCounter">1</em>
      <span class="listing__address--full" itemprop="address" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
      <span class="jsMapBubbleAddress" itemprop="streetAddress">340-600 Crowfoot Cres NW</span>, <span class="jsMapBubbleAddress" itemprop="addressLocality">Calgary</span>, <span class="jsMapBubbleAddress" itemprop="addressRegion">AB</span> <span class="jsMapBubbleAddress" itemprop="postalCode">T3G 0B4</span></span>
      <a class="listing__direction" data-analytics='{"lk_listing_id":"100971374","lk_non-ad-rollup":"0","lk_page_num":"1","lk_pos":"in_listing","lk_proximity":"14.5","lk_directory_heading":[{"085100":[{"00910600":"1"},{"00911000":"1"}]}],"lk_geo_tier":"in","lk_area":"left_1a","lk_relevancy":"1","lk_name":"directions-step1","lk_pos_num":"1","lk_se_id":"e292d1d2-f130-463d-8f0c-7dd66800dead_Tm90YXJ5_Q2FsZ2FyeSwgQUI_56","lk_ev":"link","lk_product":"l2"}' href="/merchant/directions/100971374?what=Notary&amp;where=Calgary%2C+AB&amp;useContext=true" rel="nofollow" title="Get direction to Calgary's Notary Public">Get directions »</a>
   </div>
   <div class="listing__details">
      <p class="listing__details__teaser" itemprop="description">We  offer you a convenient, quick and affordable solution for your Notary Public or Commissioner for Oaths in Calgary needs.</p>
   </div>
   <div class="listing__ratings--root">
      <div class="listing__ratings ratingWarp" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
         <meta content="5" itemprop="ratingValue"/>
         <meta content="1" itemprop="ratingCount"/>
         <span class="ypStars" data-analytics-group="stars" data-clicksent="false" data-rating="rating5" title="Ratings: 5 out of 5 stars">
         <span class="star1" data-analytics-name="stars" data-label="Optional : Why did you hate it?" title="I hated it"></span>
         <span class="star2" data-analytics-name="stars" data-label="Optional : Why didn't you like it?" title="I didn't like it"></span>
         <span class="star3" data-analytics-name="stars" data-label="Optional : Why did you like it?" title="I liked it"></span>
         <span class="star4" data-analytics-name="stars" data-label="Optional : Why did you really like it?" title="I really liked it"></span>
         <span class="star5" data-analytics-name="stars" data-label="Optional : Why did you love it?" title="I loved it"></span>
         </span><a class="listing__ratings__count" data-analytics='{"lk_listing_id":"100971374","lk_non-ad-rollup":"0","lk_page_num":"1","lk_pos":"in_listing","lk_proximity":"14.5","lk_directory_heading":[{"085100":[{"00910600":"1"},{"00911000":"1"}]}],"lk_geo_tier":"in","lk_area":"left_1","lk_relevancy":"1","lk_name":"read_yp_reviews","lk_pos_num":"1","lk_se_id":"e292d1d2-f130-463d-8f0c-7dd66800dead_Tm90YXJ5_Q2FsZ2FyeSwgQUI_56","lk_ev":"link","lk_product":"l2"}' href="/bus/Alberta/Calgary/Calgary-s-Notary-Public/100971374.html?what=Notary&amp;where=Calgary%2C+AB&amp;useContext=true#ypgReviewsHeader" rel="nofollow" title="1 of Review for Calgary's Notary Public">1<span class="hidden-phone"> YP review</span></a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="listing__details detailsWrap">
      <ul>
         <li><a href="/search/si/1/Notaries/Calgary%2C+AB" title="Notaries">Notaries</a>
            ,
         </li>
         <li><a href="/search/si/1/Notaries+Public/Calgary%2C+AB" title="Notaries Public">Notaries Public</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

There are many `div`s with `listing__right article hasIcon`. I am using for loop to extract the information.

The  python code I have written so far is.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si-rat/1/Notary/Calgary%2C+AB'
response = requests.get(url)
content = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
g_data=soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'listing__right article  hasIcon'})

for item in g_data:
    print item.find('h3').text
    #print item.contents[2].find_all('em', attrs={'class': 'itemCounter'})[1].text
    print item.find_all(class_='jsMapBubbleAddress').text
```

Comment: `find_all` returns a list, and lists in Python do not have a `text` property or attribute. Try iterating over that list returned on the last line of your code.

Comment: I want only first matching element

Comment: print item.find_all(class_='jsMapBubbleAddress')[0].text

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question.

Answer (score 2):

find_all returns a list which has no 'text' attribute so you are getting an error, not sure what output you are looking for, but this code seems to work ok:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si-rat/1/Notary/Calgary%2C+AB'
response = requests.get(url)
content = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
g_data=soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'listing__right article  hasIcon'})

for item in g_data:
    print item.find('h3').text
    #print item.contents[2].find_all('em', attrs={'class': 'itemCounter'})[1].text
    items = item.find_all(class_='jsMapBubbleAddress')
    for item in items:
        print item.text
```